# Want to open tcl/tk code in single window

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to run following tcl/tk code in single window, but when I run the below using `wish yep.tcl` it opens two windows as in picture below. I want only one window i.e `okie`

[image: 1]

What changes are required?

```
proc yep {} {
    toplevel .t
    wm geometry .t 300x200-5+40
    wm title .t "okie"
    label .t.n -text "CELL"
    grid .t.n -rowspan 2 -columnspan 5
}
yep
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating another toplevel window, `.t`, in addition to the default one called `.`. To work with only a single window, either use the default one or withdraw the default one.

### Using the default

```
proc yep {} {
    wm geometry . 300x200-5+40
    wm title . "okie"
    label .n -text "CELL"
    grid .n -rowspan 2 -columnspan 5
}
yep
```

### Withdrawing the default

```
proc yep {} {
    toplevel .t
    wm geometry .t 300x200-5+40
    wm title .t "okie"
    label .t.n -text "CELL"
    grid .t.n -rowspan 2 -columnspan 5

    # Hide the unwanted window
    wm withdraw .
    # Make the application go away when we close the visible window
    wm protocol .t WM_DELETE_WINDOW { exit }
}
yep
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `toplevel` creates an extra window. If you just want to use the main window, skip the invocation of `toplevel` and use `.` instead of `.t`. (`.t.n` becomes `.n`, of course.)

Comment: @Yash In such cases, I like to give variables to the windows. E.g. in this case, `set w .` then `toplevel $w`, `label $w.n` etc so that if you had `set w .t` at the start, you can change it to `set w .` at one point only without breaking code below.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Not getting `..n` here. Are you on 8.6.4? I vaguely remember it not working in the past which I think might have been changed sometime since.

Comment: Or alternatively just hide the default window by doing `wm withdraw .`

Comment: yes @Jerry ,that is not working ...it's giving me this error.  Error in startup script: window name "" already exists in parent
    while executing
"toplevel $w"

Comment: @Yash: don't use `toplevel` unless you want more that one window.

Comment: @Jerry: I'm on 8.6.1, but it seems unlikely that they would have changed something as fundamental as that, at least not without bumping the minor version number.

Comment: Interesting: `set w . ; ttk::label $w.n -text hello` returns `.n` .  Of course `pack $w.n` fails.   If you're in the habit of writing code like `pack [ttk::label $w.b -text there]`, it would work.   Looks like a bug to me, but fixing it would probably break some programs.

Comment: @BradLanam: yes, and `grid $w.n` also fails. I believe widget commands replace double dots with a single dot in the beginning of the path -- possibly some other commands do as well. I'd say it's a fragile practice.